# Does adding a dataset in repeated measures change the type of test?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, t-test

I am trying to design a test and am confused between the types of experiment that I should be conducting. Here is the description of what I am doing:

It is a repeated measures test. So, a participant is first given an uncolored node-link graph G1 and asked some questions about the graph. The dependent variable is the time it takes for the participant to answer the questions. Next the same participant is given a colored graph G2 and asked a set of questions. This is counterbalanced by reversing the order of the groups. Next I repeat this procedure except that this time, I provide colored G1 and uncolored G2. In all, I have 4 conditions/groups that perform the test in order as specified below:

1. G1-uncolored G2-colored
2. G2-colored   G1-uncolored
3. G1-colored   G2-uncolored
4. G2-uncolored G1-colored

I measure the time for each case. The two graphs are almost equal. The only reason I am using two different graphs is because I cannot use the same graph in both the conditions for a group as if I did that, then the participant would remember his answers from the previous condition.

Now, I am not sure what should I call this method? Should I consider one independent variable (i.e. presence/abscence of color in the graph) or whether I consider two different IV (color + which graph is used (G1/G2?)). In other words, is this just a t-dependent test or a two-way ANOVA (dunno which one)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you counterbalanced the pictures and order only to assess colour so colour presence would be your primary variable of interest.  However, regardless of how well you controlled for picture similarity, colour could have impacted them differentially. In that case you might want to look at a colour x picture interaction because it could compromise your conclusions, point to new directions for research, or both. A picture main effect wouldn't really mean anything.

Often times, in these cases one might report the main effect of colour but not fully report the interaction unless there was something meaningful in it because it's only run to assess the design, not as an outcome you want to generalize.

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion, I will be using the same colors with the same number of colors in same proportion in both the cases. The only difference between the dataset would be the configuration and labels of the graph vertices.